# MSCRM async javascript SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords return only 50 records, need all records at a time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dynamics-crm

i have some problem in async call of "SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords" function. Below are the code with my Problem

```
function Main_Method(_AnimalList)
{
    new SearchInAnimalRecords(_AnimalList);
}

function SearchInAnimalRecords(_AnimalList)
{
    $('#divProgressDetail').append('<br>Start searching Animal Records...');
    for (var i = 0; i < _AnimalList.length; i++)
        if (_AnimalList[i].SchemaName != "Lion")
            this.Process(AnimalSchemaName);
}

SearchInAnimalRecords.prototype.Process = function (AnimalSchemaName)
{
    $('#divProgressDetail').append('<br>Retriving ' + AnimalSchemaName + ' Animal Records...');
    ///SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords : Sends an asynchronous request to retrieve records.
    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords
        (
            AnimalSchemaName, /// The Schema Name of the Entity type record to retrieve.
            "$select=" + AnimalSchemaName + "Id", /// A String representing the OData System Query Options to control the data returned
            function (AnimalRecords) // "AnimalRecords" only contain 50 records
```

This function that will be passed through and be called for each page of records returned.
                 Each page is 50 records. If you expect that more than one page of records will be returned,
                 this function should loop through the results and push the records into an array outside of the function.
                 Use the OnComplete event handler to know when all the records have been processed.

```
            {
                var length = AnimalRecords.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    var guid = AnimalRecords[i][AnimalSchemaName + 'Id'];
                    var IsGuidMatch = IsKeyGuidMatchWith(guid);
                    if (IsGuidMatch)
                    {
                        $('#divProgressDetail').append('<br>Key animal found in ' + AnimalSchemaName + ' Records.');
                        $('#divProgressDetail').append('<br>Searching stop.');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            function () /// The function that will be passed through and be called by a failed response. 
            {
                $('#divProgressDetail').append('<br>Error while Retriving ' + AnimalSchemaName + ' Records.');
            },
            function () /// OnComplete EventHandler The function that will be called when all the requested records have been returned. No parameters are passed to this function.
            {
                $('#divProgressDetail').append('<br>Completed searching in ' + AnimalSchemaName + ' Records.');
            }
        );
}
```

in Process function, their is one anonymous function which accept one parameter named as "AnimalRecords". So problem is this AnimalRecords only contains 50 records, i need here all the records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a limitations on number of records returned. Each time that you retrieve records, only the top 50 records in your query are returned. If there are more than 50 records, there will be a " > node in XML or a JSON__next property at the end of the result set. You can use the URL value in that node or property to continue with the next set of records. The URL contains a $skiptoken parameter that provides information about the paging boundary

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx

If you want to access all records  try to use xrmservicetoolkit

XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.QueryAll: a method to return all records (>5k+).

http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using Dynamics CRM 2011. The help files provided in the SDK earlier returned only the first 50, but it was modified in the latest SDK release. If you have access to the latest SDK for CRM 2011, the helper file in that for the 'RetrieveMultiple' jQuery call already handles the 50 record limit by its own; meaning the implementation is already there to retrieve all records instead of just the first 50.

Try downloading the latest SDK and use that code. You should get the desired results.